# Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 - Not installing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

I have just had a major "incident" with my PC and have had to rebuild. I took the opportunity to install VS2013 (previous was 2012) and I installed the latest version from MSDN (en_visual_studio_ultimate_2013_x86_dvd_3175319.iso)

After all up and running, it tells me Update 1 is available and I have tried all sorts to try and install but each time, the Visual Studio Banner label pops up and then disappears in less than a second.

I have tried all sorts of permutations such is downloading inside/outside Visual Studio, launching inside/outside VS, downloading full ISO (rather that web installer) etc.

Help->About says v12.0.21005.1 REL

Am running Win 8 x64

Any suggestions?

Comment: my one failed but maybe 'cos my visual studio is already on update 5.

Comment: The `machine.config` file might also be corrupt, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076943/visual-studio-2015-update-3-not-installing-no-error-or-feedback/39787749#39787749.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using commentary from above from @leshy84 the log files showed **Error 0x80131902: Failed to run per-user mode.**

Researching that then pointed me to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1220584d-2576-4d64-8359-a946ca208041/cant-install-vs-2012-on-win7-enterprise?forum=vssetup and what worked for me was

1. Remove .Net 3.5 and 4.0 from Programs and Features
2. Reboot
3. Re-add .Net 3.5/4
4. Reboot
5. Install Update 1

Comment: @barlop the log file can probably be enabled by starting the setup from the command line with the "/log setup.log" argument.

Answer (score 6):

In my case there was no C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config file. There was only machine.config.default. So I copy it and rename to machine.config. Works fine :)

Comment: Your method worked!!! This is what I did:

I renamed the machine.config file to "machine.config.backup" and made a copy of machine.config.default and renamed it to "machine.config"!!

Thanks mate!!

Comment: You need to put on a super-hero cape and go to all the forums with this problem and post this. This has cost me 5 working days. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all files/folders in C:\ProgramData\Package Cache ("%ProgramData%\Package Cache") and install the update again

Comment: Rather than delete, I moved the whole folder to the desktop... but same issue.... just flashes!

Comment: Maybe then it makes sense to have a look at its logs? It seems they are in %TEMP% folder by default for WiX bundles

Comment: Well, this is the line in the log file I suspect is the issue.... so will now research that...**Error 0x80131902: Failed to run per-user mode.**

Comment: It seems you have problem with .NET

Comment: Apparently so...

I followed through <http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1220584d-2576-4d64-8359-a946ca208041/cant-install-vs-2012-on-win7-enterprise?forum=vssetup> and removed .Net 3.5 and 4; reboot; added back .net; reboot; and voila... patching is now running