# How to resolve 'hash value is not correct' errors when installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, updates

I updated my Windows 7 x64 professional through Windows Update, then fired up Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 to install .NET Core.

It partially installed with the following errors on screen. What can I do to resolve them?

[image: Error installing visual studio 2015 enterprise update 3]

Taking a cue from [Visual Studio 2015 update 3 not installing (no error or feedback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076943/visual-studio-2015-update-3-not-installing-no-error-or-feedback), I tried through the control panel and got the following screen which shows that update 3 is already installed.

My control panel still lists Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2

[image: Trying to update from control panel]

When running the VS 2015 Update 3 installer again I get the following screen.

[image: running the VS 2015 Update 3 installer again]