# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 not being applied after installer runs to completion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Update 3 for Visual Studio 2015 on top of an Update 2 instance, but looks like it doesn't want to. The installer launches and runs to completion (I see the "Setup Completed" dialog), but then when I run VS I see that it's still on Update 2 (v14.0.25123.00).

I tried to [start the installer from Programs and Features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186826/4574), to run the installer as administrator, and to reset after the install. None of this worked.

If that helps, the Update 3 feature appears as "(Updated)" in the install dialog. Perhaps Windows thinks that Update 3 is already installed or something?

[image]

Is there something I can do other than fully reinstalling Visual Studio?

**Note: not a duplicate** of [Visual Studio 2015 update 3 not installing (no error or feedback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076943/visual-studio-2015-update-3-not-installing-no-error-or-feedback) because in my case the installer is actually appearing and running to completion.